# Limiting Cassandra query syntax for clients

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

We plan to use Cassandra 3.x and we want to allow our customers to connect to Cassandra directly for exporting the data into their data warehouses.
They will connect via ODBC from remote.

Is there any way to prevent that the customer executes huge or bad `SELECT` statements that will result in a high load for all nodes? We use an extra data center in our replication strategy where only customers can connect, so live system will not be affected. But we want to setup some workers that will run on this *shadow* system also. Most important thing is, that a connected remote client will not have any noticable impact on other remote connections or our local worker jobs. There is a materialized view already and I want to force customers to get data based on primary key only (i.e. disallow usage of `ALLOW FILTERING`). It would be great also, if one can limit the number of rows returned (e.g. 1 million) to prevent a pull of all data.

Is there a best practise for this use case?

I know of BlackRocks video related to multi-tenant strategy in C* which advises to use `tenant_id` in schema. That is what we're doing already, but how can I ensure security/isolation via ODBC connected tenants/customers? Or do I have to write an API on my own which handles security?

Comment: I would recommend to expose access via API, not via ODBC - at least you would have greater control on what is executed, and enforce tenant_id, and other checks... But this could be quite a lot of work, but maybe you could utilize Apache Calcite, or something like: https://calcite.apache.org/docs/cassandra_adapter.html

Comment: @AlexOtt it's a long time since your post and no new answers, sadly. But as I think my question is relevant for other users, would you be so kind and make an answer from your comment, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to expose access via API, not via ODBC - at least you would have greater control on what is executed, and enforce tenant_id, and other checks, like limits, etc.  You can try to utilize the Cassandra's CQL parser to decompose query, and put all required things back.

Theoretically, you can could utilize [Apache Calcite](http://calcite.apache.org), for example. It has implementation of JDBC driver that could be used, plus there is existing [Cassandra adapter](http://calcite.apache.org/docs/cassandra_adapter.html) that you can modify to accomplish your task (mapping authentication into tenant_ids, etc.), but this will be quite a lot of work.